# Is there a way to installed python module with homebrew from official binary installed python?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, homebrew

I am using Python3.6 that installed with official binary package.

I was installed PyGObject3 with homebrew.
I want to use PyGObject3 from Python that installed with binary package.
(there is no PyGObject3 on PyPI and I don't want to install python3.6 from homebrew.)

How can I use homebrew installed package from official binary python?

OS: macOS 10.12.3

Comment: Homebrew isn't the only way of installing things you know

Comment: The recommended way is to slways use pip

Comment: @abccd There is no pygobject3 in PyPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install PyGObject3 without using brew to install it to an custom python.

```
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/3.10/pygobject-3.10.0.tar.xz
tar -xf pygobject-3.10.0.tar.xz
cd pygobject-3.10.0
./configure --with-python=PATH
make && make install
```

replace PATH with path to your python excutable, for example:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python`

The link is from the newest stable release of pygobject3.